# Simple contact form not working

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make a **simple contact form**,
I have two files, contact.php and the index.php

I want that  couple of options will appear in my index.php file in the **"Enquiry type**"   those options i put in array in th contact.php file like this:

```html
<?php

class Contact{

 public static $types = array(

    1 => 'Product enquiry',
    2 => 'Billing enquiry',
    3 => 'Support enquiry'


  );
}
```

I have also included contact.php in the index.php file:

```html
<?php require_once('file:///D:/Simple%20Contact%20Form/Liberay/Contact.php'); ?>
```

But  after lot of attempts, I cant see in the drop down field any  of that options, so probably its something with connection maybe? And when I'm trying out php code, should i have to put it in local server like Xampp?

this is the full code from index.php:

```html
<?php require_once('file:///D:/Simple%20Contact%20Form/Liberay/Contact.php'); ?>

<!DOCOTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>Simple contact form with PHP</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///D:/Simple%20Contact%20Form/CSS/core.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="formContact" class="large-8 large-centered columns custom"> 
<fieldset>

<legend>Simple Contact Form with PHP</legend>

<div class="large-6 columns">

 <label for="first_name">First name: *</label>
 <input 
 type="text"
 name="first_name"
     id="first_name"
     placeholder="Your first name"/>
 </div>

 <div class="large-6 columns">

 <label for="last_name">Last name: *</label>
 <input type="text"
 name="last_name"
     id="last_name"
     placeholder="Your last name"/>
 </div>

 <div class="large-6 columns">

 <label for="first_name">Email address: *</label>
 <input type="email"
 name="email"
     id="email"
     placeholder="Your Email address"/>
 </div>

<div class="large-6 columns">

 <label for="type">Enquiry type: *</label>
 <select
  name="type"
   id="type">
    
    <option value="">Select one</option>

   <?php if (!empty(Contact::$types)) { ?>

   <?php foreach(Contact::$types as $id => $type) { ?>

   <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php  echo $type; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>

    </select>

</div>
<div class="large-12 columns">
 <label for="enquiry">Enquiry: *</label>
 <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" placeholder=" Your message"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="large-12 columns">

<button class="button small">Send message</button>

 </div>


</fieldset>

</form>

<script src="file:///D:/Simple%20Contact%20Form/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="file:///D:/Simple Contact Form/js/core.js"></script>

</body>




</html>
```

*Sorry if there is little bit of mess, but I'm trying my best (-:

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with XAMPP, then put all your files under **htdocs** folder. You have mentioned

```
<?php require_once('file:///D:/Simple%20Contact%20Form/Liberay/Contact.php'); ?>
```

- which refers to local file path.

Comment: hey!  yes.. i change it like that:
<?php require_once('file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/ContactForm/Library/Contact.php'); ?>

Comment: but when i get inside the index this is the error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in D:\xampp\htdocs\ContactForm\index.php on line 60

Comment: absolute file path doesn't make sense in a apache server, putting the files under htdocs & using relative file path is the first thing to be done.

Comment: Relative path means: <?php require_once('ContactForm/Liberay/Contact.php'); ?>